# Configure dynamic assets_host in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want Rails 3 to dynamically grab assets depending on current domain:

mysite.com - assets.mysite.com
mysite.ru - assets.mysite.ru

Is it possible out of the box? Or I should implement it manually?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

In config/environments/production.rb etc.

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets." << request.host
```

Comment: We tried this, but rails fails to find request object. It seems that it is not exist during initialization

Comment: When i use this in my development.rb file, it shows like ``method_missing': undefined method `request' ` do i have to require any pakage at top of the file for this?

Comment: This is not the correct way to specify. You have to assign a Proc, or anything that responds to a `call` instance method that takes a path and a request.

Answer (score 12):

Try sending a proc to asset_host, which yields both the asset path and request:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = proc {|path, request|
  "http://assets." << request.host
}
```

Comment: By including the http, you limit the pages to include assets from non-SSL/https sources. Considering that your page could be SSL, its not a bad idea to let rails add the appropriate schema.

Answer (score 9):

Note the key differences from other solutions in the solutions below:

1. Using request.domain instead of request.host since most assets hosts would not be assets0.www.domain.com but rather assets0.domain.com
2. Using the source.dash and modulo will ensure that the same asset is served from the same asset server. This is key for page performance.
3. Filtering by asset type/path.

I have always done something like this:

```
  config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request|
    "http#{request.ssl? ? 's' : ''}://cdn#{(source.hash % 3)}." << request.domain # cdn0-3.domain.com
  }
```

Or if you have multiple asset/cdn hosts you could decide to be selective about what kind of assets are served from what host like so:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request|
  case source
  when /^\/images/
    "http#{request.ssl? ? 's' : ''}://cdn#{(source.hash % 2)}." << request.domain # cdn0-1.domain.com
  when /^\/javascripts/, /^\/stylesheets/
    "http#{request.ssl? ? 's' : ''}://cdn#{(source.hash % 2) + 2}." << request.domain # cdn2-3.domain.com
  else
    "http#{request.ssl? ? 's' : ''}://cdn4." << request.domain # cdn4.domain.com
  end
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: use `Zlib.crc32(source)` instead of `source.hash` as source.hash value is not consistent across machines and processes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you meaning [subdomains](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html#method-i-subdomains)?

```
subdomains(tld_length = 1)

Returns all the subdomains as an array, so ["dev", "www"] would be returned for “dev.www.rubyonrails.org“. You can specify a different tld_length, such as 2 to catch ["www"] instead of ["www", "rubyonrails"] in “www.rubyonrails.co.uk“.
```