# Issue with using CDN and https: (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cdn

In my Rails application, i have used CDN. I have configured the cdn by adding cdn url to

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://cdn.mydomain.com"
```

in production.rb file.

Now i am trying to have `https://` for certain pages like **Sign In and Sign Up**

But as the assets are served from CDN, the https conflicts with the cdn path.

My solution to this to make the sign in and sign up pages not to use the cdn assets and should point
as local assets.

is my solution correct? if so how do i restrict certain layout files from using CDN asset path?

Comment: Does your CDN support retrieval over SSL?

Comment: No.. i have only CDN with `http` service. 
Do i have to make my CDN ssl too?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to.  See my response below, hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I would look at this response: [Configure dynamic assets_host in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966451/configure-dynamic-assets-host-in-rails-3)

What I think you would want to do is change asset_host to be dynamic based on whether your page is served over https or not.  Something like:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request|
"#{request.ssl? ? '/assets' : 'http://cdn.mydomain.com'}"
```

}

My syntax may be a little off as I'm typing it up on the fly but it should be close to what you need.

Comment: I added `config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request| "#{request.ssl? ? 'http://cdn-devs-in.mydomain.com' : 'http://cdn-dev-in.mydomain.com'}" }
` in my production.rb file.. but when i precompile this.. i get the below error..

`rake aborted!
This asset host cannot be computed without a request in scope. Remove the second argument to your asset_host Proc if you do not need the request, or make it optional.
  (in /var/www/MyDomain-web/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary`

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE :** The code `request.try(:ssl?)` always returns false even when i run the https version.
I am working on finding the solution, will post it once i find it.

Found the solution

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new do |*args|
  source, request = args
  if request.try(:ssl?)
    'https://mydomain.com'
  else
    'http://cdn.mydomain.com'
  end
end
```

Comment: @JeffSteil : Actually the code `request.try(:ssl?)` is responding with `false` always..

Comment: Can't you use just use request.ssl? instead of request.try(:ssl?)?

Comment: Nope.. only after trying that, i used try(:ssl?)