# Rails: Excluding images from being linked from CDN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, amazon-cloudfront

I have `CDN` asset hosting working for `js`, `css` and `static images`.  But I would like to exclude images that are generated dynamically (using `send_file`) from `CDN` and would like browsers to go directly to my app URL for such images,

i.e. go to http://www.myapp.com/user_photos/2/images/5

But the send_file URL gets output as http://cdn.myapp.com/user_photo/2/images/5

The reason is that the controller where the image #view exists requires authorization, and for some reason the cookie is not making it all the way back to the app server.  So even if i wanted to use the `CDN` in the middle as a relay for the dynamically generated image, it fails controller authorization (using cancan/devise for auth)

In production.rb i have:

`config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://cdn.myapp.com/"`

I tried the following in carrier wave configure but it did not work:

`config.asset_host = "http://www.myapp.com/"`

Any thoughts on how to exclude certain routes from exclusion by CDN?

Comment: strange it should work out of the box weird just try overriding the `url` method

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have conditions set in `production.rb` file which sets the asset_host based on URL pattern.  In my case, i wanted anything in user_photos to be served from a different asset host than all other static assets:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source|
  case source
  when /\/user_photos\//
    APP_CONFIG['dynamic_photos_root_url']
  else
    APP_CONFIG['asset_cdn']
end
}
```

Carrier-wave config changes did not do anything, so i ended up removing them.

CDN is cloudfront by Amazon, and they do something funky with the cookies which i did not understand even when i set the behavior of the CDN to pass through all cookies.

Following discussion was key in figuring out the solution:
[Configure dynamic assets_host in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966451/configure-dynamic-assets-host-in-rails-3)

I wonder if there is a way to get Amazon cloudfront to work where it caches this image and on subsequent hits by the same user, it passes the cookie to the origin, gets authentication and then serves the same cached image to the browser.